# Read the line from a text file with the particular string using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file that contains log data. I have retrieve Serial No, Output status, Pin No etc from the log file.

My log file look like below. It has lot of contents.

```
"FORMAT=U2"
"BEGIN HEADER"
"TS=600581"
"ST=1001038"
"TC=60055"
"PIN=100577"
"SN=GXT220.1"
```

I have to read the file and print PIN is 100577 and Serial No is GXT220.1. I have do the same for may files and the line no is not same for all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want ---> Reading through the textfile and extract out specific information in a line with constant indicator.

If so, this is what i will do.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, ReadTextFile ' object
Dim Textline ' string/variant
Dim PinNumber, Serial ' Output

FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("File.txt", 1) ' Open text with read only mode

Do Until ReadTextFile.AtEndOfStream
   Textline = ReadTextFile.Readline()

   If Instr(Textline, "PIN=") Then ' If textline contain string "PIN="
      PinNumber = Split(Textline, "=")(1) ' Split the textline  with "=" indicator
   End If

   If Instr(Textline, "SN=") Then
      Serial = Split(Textline, "=")(1)
   End If

Loop ' Read through every line
```

This example only works if you have only one indicator in one file. And also your indicator is the same to all txt file. Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you required to do on more file , just simply do a looping.

'Set FSOFolder = FSO.GetFolder("FolderName\") 

For Each Objfile in FSOFolder.Files 'loop through all file in folder
Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(Objfile.path, 1)
Next'

Answer (score 0):

Use

1. .[ReadAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt(v=vs.84).aspx)() to read a file into a string
2. a [RegExp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62(v=vs.84).aspx) to parse the string
3. a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) to store/access the values

As in:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim s    : s        = goFS.OpenTextFile("43009791.txt").ReadAll()
Dim r    : Set r    = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Multiline = True
r.Pattern = "^""(\w+)=([^""]+)"""
Dim d    : Set d   = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim m
For Each m In r.Execute(s)
    d(m.Submatches(0)) = m.Submatches(1)
Next
Dim k
For Each k In d.Keys()
    WScript.Echo k, "=>", d(k)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 43009791.vbs
FORMAT => U2
TS => 600581
ST => 1001038
TC => 60055
PIN => 100577
SN => GXT220.1
```